# Chamada de métodos genéricos em C#

Tags: c#, .net, genéricos

Construí um método genérico que me atende bem, porém estou com dificuldade na chamada deste método.

```
 public List<T> CriaLista<T>(params T[] pars)
  {
            List<T> lista = new List<T>();
            foreach (T elem in pars)
            {
                lista.Add(elem);
            }
            return lista;
  }
```

Preciso que seja retornada uma lista do tipo `T` mesmo. Porém não estou sabendo como realizar a chamada desta lista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você chama o método como qualquer outro passando o array do tipo `T`

Abaixo eu criei uma classe chamada `Pessoa` que eu utilizo na classe `MinhaClasse` onde eu chamo o método que você criou passando as instâncias do objeto do tipo `Pessoa`.

```
public class Pessoa
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}

public class MinhaClasse
{
    public void CarregarPessoas()
    {
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = CriarLista(new Pessoa{Nome = "Foo1"}, new Pessoa{Nome = "Foo2"}, new Pessoa{Nome = "Foo3"});
        foreach (var item in pessoas)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Nome);
        }
    }

    public List<T> CriarLista<T>(params T[] pars)
    {
        List<T> lista = new List<T>();
        foreach (T elem in pars)
        {
            lista.Add(elem);
        }

        return lista;
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando em [.NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KaXPNx)

Answer (score 4):

Não tem segredo algum, se estava com dificuldade poderia ter mostrado o código pra gente ver o que estava errado. É só chamar e passar os parâmetros. A não ser que esteja em uma situações específicas que crie alguma dificuldade para o compilador.

Aproveitei para simplificar este código, ele faz bem pouco. Na verdade tão pouco que se não for para usar como abstração ele nem deveria existir.

```
using static System.Console;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        foreach (var item in CriarLista(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)) WriteLine(item);
    }
    public static List<T> CriarLista<T>(params T[] pars) => pars.ToList();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/bq46Ji). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/elFtVS). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Generics/CallGenericMethodParams.cs).